# Hash coding in Java negative numbers

Tags: java, hash, hashtable, hashcode, negative-number

So this code produces hash codes:

```
int x = 33;
int hash = 7;
for (String str: list) {

    for (int o = 0; o < str.length(); o++) {
        hash = ((33*hash) + str.charAt(o));
    }
```

However some of these are negative. It's required that they be dealt with during overload so that they can be placed into a hash table as I then have to perform a look up on them. Don't enquire as to whether they have to be dealt with, they just do, they cannot be negative numbers.

I have to do it via this method:

```
((ak + b) mod p) mod T; where p is prime.
```

Has anyone any ideas?

Comment: Get the absolute value of the result.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis What do you mean? how?

Comment: What do you mean _how_? How to get an absolute value? I'll let you figure that out.

Comment: You should have a use at `BigInteger`; or, if performance is a concern for you and you deal with large numbers, have a look at [apfloat](http://www.apfloat.org/apfloat_java/)

Comment: What do you mean by 'during overload'?

Comment: @EJP I mean when it overloads, so becomes negative.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want them to be negative just add

```
hash = Math.abs(hash)
```

this will give a non negative number. 
But be aware, that you loose a Bit ;)

Comment: looks more complicated now, why that way? and if so hmm mathematical, another question: why 33?

Comment: 33 is a prime number and is a set value of horner's polynomial method. This way because we have been told this way haha

Comment: 33 = 3 * 11 
 Anyway, my suggestion: use the best hash possible (there are others) and if you do not want them to be negative, make them non-negative. loosing a Bit of resolution - half the space.